# How to run a function when Materialize.css autocomplete is not selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, autocomplete, materialize

I'm trying to write a function that will execute when the a Materialize.css autocomplete option is *not* selected. Is this possible? Basically I want to automatically add a value to an email field based on a user-selected autocomplete option in the name field, which works fine. But I would also like that email value to disappear when the user types in a custom name, and so far I can't get it to work without some kind of "clear" button. I've tried writing an if/else statement like this:

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
  data: {
    //Data options
  },
  limit: 20, 
  onAutocomplete: function(val) {
    if ( $("#personname").val() == "last name, first" ) {
      $("#personemail").val("email@business.com");
    }
    else {
      $("#personemail").val("");
    }
  },
  minLength: 1, 
});
```

But this doesn't appear to work because (I think) this function will only run if autocomplete has executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onAutocomplete` function is not needed in your specific case. The way I would handle it would be to create a listener on the `$("#personemail")` field that will check to see if there is a value present in the autocomplete.

I've created something that (I think) solves the problem you are having, check it out at JSfiddle:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#personname').val('last name, first'); // proof of concept, assuming a user would input this
  Materialize.updateTextFields(); // remove it and you can see the visual bug

  $('.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: {
      "apple": null,
      "banana": null,
      "yellow": null,
      "purple": null,
      "green": null,
      "blue": null
    },
    limit: 20,
    onAutocomplete: function(val) {
      if ($('#personname').val() == 'last name, first') {
        $('#personemail').val('email@business.com');
        Materialize.updateTextFields();
      }
    },
    minLength: 1,
  });

  $('#personname').change(function() {
    $("#personemail").val('');
  });
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v22/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">add</i>
        <input type="text" id="personname">
        <label for="personname">Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
        <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">personpin</i>
        <input type="text" id="personemail">
        <label for="personemail">Email</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Hi, I am fairly new to frontend programming, and angular in particular.

In your example, where do I put this function? this looks like javascript and all I use is typescript....

$(function() {
  $('#personname').val('last name, first');
  Materialize.updateTextFields();